# How do I insert a formula/calculation like this into an IFS or other similar function in Excel?

Tags: excel

I've looked everywhere online, but there shouldn't seem to be an appropriate answer.

```
=IFS(D2="DgovWIN","D+"(B2-C2)/(B2+C2),D2="RgovWIN","R+"(C2-B2)/(C2+B2),D2="govTIE","0")

=IFS(D2="DgovWIN",D+(B2-C2)/(B2+C2),D2="RgovWIN",R+(C2-B2)/(C2+B2),D2="govTIE","0")

=IFS(D2="DgovWIN","D+(B2-C2)/(B2+C2)",D2="RgovWIN","R+(C2-B2)/(C2+B2)",D2="govTIE","0")
```

None of these work, so do I have to make the numbers separately, in a different/new column?

Comment: D and R have to have values, perhaps as named ranges. Otherwise you are going to return string/text.

Comment: @Jeeped Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. For example, if the adjacent box gives out "DgovWIN", and the calculation of (B2-C2)/(B2+C2) returns the value "3", then I would want the cell to show "D+3".

Comment: something like: `=IF(D2="DgovWIN","D+"&(B2-C2)/(B2+C2),IF(D2="RgovWIN","R+"&(C2-B2)/(C2+B2),IF(D2="govTIE","0","")))`???

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close with a couple of those. You just need to incorporate the & as a string concatenation operator.

```
=IFS(D2="DgovWIN", "D+"&(B2-C2)/(B2+C2), D2="RgovWIN", "R+"&(C2-B2)/(C2+B2), D2="govTIE", "0")
```

[image]